# Python replace function outputs different results

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, replace

```
s="|0000011111111|"
print s.replace(s[9:12],'   ')
```

...output is `|00000      11|`

```
s="|0000012345678|"
print s.replace(s[9:12],'   ')
```

...output is `|00000123   78|`

I only want to replace `s[9:12]` to three spaces, why is the first output incorrect?

Comment: Because replace takes a string value. Where that string value is taken from, is not part of the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`str.replace()` will replace **all** occurrences of the string you pass in as the first argument. It doesn't matter here that the first argument here is created from a slice, the `str.replace()` method is not given any information as to where that string came from. Instead, the `str.replace()` method starts at position 0 and searches forward, it doesn't matter where the substring is found in the input string.

So you are really just doing this:

```
string_to_replace = s[9:12]
s.replace(string_to_replace, '   ')
```

or even just

```
s.replace('111', '   ')
```

These all have the exact same effect.

Your second example only worked because the `s[9:12]` string value is unique in `s`; there is only one occurrence to replace, at exactly the right location.

Because `s[9:12]` is the string `'111'`, you asked Python to replace all occurances of that string in `s` with spaces, and there are two such sequences to replace.

You are far better off explicitly slicing the input string:

```
s = s[:9] + '   ' + s[12:]
```

That takes all text *before* the part you want to replace and all the text *after*, and puts three spaces in between those two substrings.

Answer (score 6):

In the first case `s[9:12]` is `'111'`. You code replaces *every* non-overlapping instance of `'111'` with three spaces.

Answer (score 3):

If you call `s.replace(s[9:12], '   ')` then Python does *not* interpret this as "*replace the characters at index 9 to index 12 with empty characters*". It first evaluates `s[9:12]` to `'111'`. And then it will start replacing groups of three ones with spaces, regardless where these are found.

In case you want to replace the characters at a specific index, you can use:

```
print s[:9] + '   ' + s[12:]
```

Here we take the string until (without) index 9, followed by three spaces, followed by the characters starting from index 12.

Note that in case the original string does not contain 12 or more characters, we will still add three spaces to it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

> `str.replace(old, new[, count])`
>
> **Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new.** If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

So `replace()` does not replace ***at*** a position, it replaces ***all occurrences of a substring found inside your string*** by another given string.

- In your first example, `s[9:12]` is equal to `111`, so all the occurrences of this substring are replaced.
- In your second *"working"* example, you're lucky because `s[9:12]` is equal to `456` and since there is only one occurrence of this substring in `s` at `s[9:12]`, it is correctly replaced.